# ASP.net Transparent edit control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, input

I am looking for a custom control.

Transparent text edit control.

I m looking for a text edit control with a transparent background with no border.
The properties are as follows:

Text font, size, color etc.
Text Vertical alignment
Text Horizontal alignment
Control Size

Events are standard extensions of something like a text box.

can you help me where can i find?

Comment: ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: This is more of a html/style question

Answer (score 3):

This may help you [AlphaBlendTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/alphablendtextbox.aspx) - A transparent/translucent textbox for .NET

For AsP.Net (you didn't mentioned that before):
Its super easy just use this CSS with normal Input Tag and you will have a Text Box which is Transparent and with no borders.:

```
background-color:transparent;
border-width:0px;
```

Comment: i m sorry i forgot to mention i want in webforms.. not winforms